# Critical Viewer Error - Cannot Load XAML Resource

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, iis-7

I have a silverlight application and it works completely fine in VS2010 then when I upload it to IIS7 and try to browse it I get an error saying

"An error occurred during initialization and the Viewer could not be started. This may be due to network connectivity problems, viewer configuration problems, or site configuration problems"

Further details of the error are:

"Cannot load Xaml resource from /config/themes/map/map.xaml."

If I navigate to the folder where it says that it cannot load it I can see that it is there and that it looks to be in the correct formatting(as it should be if it was working on my local machine). So I thought maybe permissions were stopping it so I checked that and there are sufficint permissions to access the file.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the error was not very specific but I figured out that it was because of trying to request images via httpRequest from a https website. Silverlight seems to be very strict about cross scheme requests like this and won't allow it. As in there is no work around except for having both sides being http or https.

Solution was to make both http and then it worked.

Source of information from Microsoft at this like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)